# WSO2 Identity Server load balance behind F5 BigIP

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, f5, wso2-identity-server

We have several applications behind an F5 load balancer now.  The SSL is terminated at the F5 load balancer, and the traffic is sent back to the server nodes as plain unencrypted http traffic.

Can the Wso2 identity server nodes be configured behind an F5, so that all traffic is plain unecrypted http traffic, and the F5 handles the SSL?

If that is not the way wso2 identity server is designed to work, could you please describe, in general terms, how to load balance wso2 behind a physical load balancer like an F5?  Or if you have any links to documents about other load balancers, that would be ideal.

I have found some guides showing how to use Apache or ELB, but they are not translating well to an F5.  The F5 is designed to act as a true proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Wso2 carbon products support HTTP/HTTPs protocols by default and since F5 supports both http/https, you can configure this. Therefore as you configure with other servers, map the IP address and the port with services that you want to map with wso2 carbon products.

This [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+NGINX+Plus) explains how to do it with Nginx. Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks you, but your article you linked to shows ssl certs being installed on the nodes as well as the front-end load balancer (nginx).  I want to know if it is possible to only install 1 cert on the load balancer, and have all communication back to the nodes by plain http traffic only.  No certs installed on the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the F5 can do [SSL Offloading](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/setting-up-ssl-offloading-termination-on-an-f5-bigip-load-balancer).  If you are concerned about the cost of SSL certificates, you could use self-signed certificates on your Identity Server nodes.

In our installation, we install the same SSL certificate (e.g., for secure.example.com) on the F5 and all the Identity Server nodes.

Hope this helps!